# Salesforce Platform Light - Login Limit

Tags: licenses

The documentation for Platform Licensing ([1](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_understanding_license_types.htm&type=5)) does not completely define some things:

(a) 10 customized objects:  Does that mean you can only create 10 custom objects in the app, or you can created more than 10 objects but users only access 10 through forms, reports etc.?

(b) I have seen comments on other sites about monthly login limits.  Is there any limit?

Comment: The 10 custom objects is a contractual rather than technical limit. The monthly piece I assume relates to the way you purchase Community Login licenses - SF assume you will have 20 daily "logins" per month per user. However, login overage is allowed and users are not prevented from logging in. SF will be in touch at some point to ask you to buy additional license subscriptions if there is overage over a 3 month+ period, or at least annually.

Comment: Thank you, that helps.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce-licensing/understand-how-licenses-work explains the licenses.